# How to detect error in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, maven

Below is a view of the package explorer of my project. I get this error on the project root and i am not able to find which is the problem. The project runs correctly without any error in the stack trace. [image]

Comment: Please post what the `Problems` tab in eclipe is showing.

Comment: The stack trace is empty. I only get the error sign on my project's root.

Comment: @laura if you cant find the Problems tab go to `Window > show view > Problems` or just hit `Alt+Shift+Q` then hit `X`

Comment: @A4L i followed your suggestion: there are 2 errors : `Cannot change version of project Dynamic Web Module to 2.5`

Comment: @laura make sure that the dependencies in your `pom.xml` and the setting in `Project > Properties > Project Facets` and doctype or schema definition in the `web.xml` are consistent

Comment: @A4L the version of the Dynamic web module is 2.3 in Project Facets and i am not able to change it to 2.5 like the version in the pom.xml

Comment: What server (and which version) do you use?

Comment: Try cleaning your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that your pom.xml contains this [dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5) (see the version)

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Make sure that your web.xml stats with the following [schema declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webapp/web_xml.html)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
   ```
3. Make sure that your Facet config for `Dynamic Web Module` is set to `2.5`.

Hit Alt+F5 to refresh the maven Project.

If you get stuck on step 3, try to delete the project from eclipse (without deleting the content!) and reimport it as maven project.

Although if your just starting up, I would recommend using a newer version of the servlet spec (at least 3.0).

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the "Problems" view.

`Window -> Show View -> Problems (or Other -> General -> Problems)`

[image: Problems view]

in this view you will find a list with errors and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to check (not in any order though)-

1. View pages. This normally isn't really an error, but eclipse keeps complaining.
2. Errors in anything apart from the views and the java source files. For example config files. This may or may not be an issue. I've been able to run with an error showing on web.xml. It worked fine on Tomcat 7 while it failed on Tomcat 6.

I am assuming there is no error in importing libraries and anything in the source because the application compiles, builds and runs without any error.